# Can one Node module make use of dependencies from a node module it depends on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

TL;DR; Is it possible to implement package inheritance in Node?  Or is there a recommended tool to help with this?

I am working in an enterprise environment containing 60+ (and growing) web apps.  We’ve also modularized components such as header/footer/sign-in/etc. so the web apps don’t need to repeat the code, and they can just pull them in as dependencies.  We also have library modules to provide things like common logging, modeling, and error handling.  We also have one main library that provides a foundation for maintenance like testing, and linting.

What I am trying to do is get access to the dependencies this main library uses in upper level modules.

```
lib-a   
   |   
   —> lib-b  
         |
         —> babel, chai, mocha, etc.
```

I would like to have lib-a “inherit” babel, chai, mocha, etc. from lib-b rather than having to specifically add the dependencies.  That way all my libraries, and eventually web apps will have the same version, and I won’t have to repeat the same dependencies in every package.json.  Nor will I need to go through the headache of having N number of teams update the 60-100 apps/libs/whatnot, and having to deal with them complaining about maintenance.

I do understand this goes against the core of npm, but on the level we are using this it’s becoming a maintenance headache.  Going more DRY would certainly have it’s benefits at this point.

So to repeat the original question at the top -  Is it possible to implement package inheritance in Node?  Or are there any recommended tools to help with this?

I have seen the following tools. Has anyone ever used them? or have thoughts on them. Are there others?
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/builder
https://github.com/Cosium/dry-dry

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea. You should assume that you don't have control over the dependencies. How else would anybody be able to make changes to the dependencies?

Suppose `lib a` from your example uses `mocha`. Since it depends on `lib b` which also depends on `mocha`, you could decide to not list `mocha` in `lib a`'s `package.json`.

If somebody refactors `lib b` to not use `mocha` anymore, `lib a` will fall all a sudden. That's not good.

We work with equally many projects. We use [Greenkeeper](https://github.com/greenkeeperio/greenkeeper), [RenovateBot](https://github.com/apps/renovate), and some tools that apply changes to all our repos at once. In the long run that's probably a better strategy for you than going against Node's dependency model.